# Circular references in REST API

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a REST API (using Django Rest Framework) and am struggling with the problem of potential circular references in the data that is returned from each endpoint.

I have decided to keep the API flat, rather than nested, as I think it makes a lot of other things (permissions, for example) more straight-forward.

So say, for instance, that I am doing the classic blog + posts + comments structure...

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    content = models.TextField()
```

If my API has endpoints like:-

```
/api/posts/1/
```

and:-

```
/api/comments/1/
```

then they could easily end up serializing to:-

```
{
    'title': 'My Title',
    'content': 'The content',
    'author': {
        // user name, email etc.
    }
}
```

and:-

```
{
    'post': {
        'title': 'My Title',
        'content': 'The content',
        'author': {
            // user name, email etc.
        }
    },
    'content': 'The comment'
}
```

Which is fine. But it means that I have to "know" to do select_related on Users when I'm fetching comments, simply because by doing that, I'm fetching the post that the comment is attached to and that has an author which is a User.

I can see this getting messy and I'm foreseeing circular references coming my way.

Is there a "recommended" way to do this kind of thing? If so, what is it? Should the "post" part of the comment serialization just return the URL of the endpoint for the post? Or is what I'm doing just fine and I shouldn't worry?!

Comment: Does this help you? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: Not really. It still means that the queryset for Comments will have to know that it needs to select all the relevant parts of the Post model that are required for the serialization of those objects.